# Using the "Previous/Next API" module with Display Suite and Colorbox Node

Tags: 7, views, display-suite, javascript

Using Drupal 7. I have a "people" content node for employee biographies. I have a views page that aggregates the display of people content types into a 5 across by 2 deep grid. Each cell is a portrait over the person's name. I've hyperlinked the image/name with a classed anchor to invoke the colorbox node function to display the particular "people" node content within a colorbox display. It's all working nicely, but I need to add one more navigational element.

I'd like to add "prev/next" links to the node, using the ["Previous/Next API"](https://drupal.org/project/prev_next) module. I've added [this code](http://www.nodeid.com/previousnext-navigation-links-drupal-7) to my template.php file as per the page. Next I'd like to add the template code for the "Colorbox" Display Suite for the "People" content type:

```
<?php
  $nextPost = pn_node($node, 'n');
  $prevPost = pn_node($node, 'p'); 
  if ($nextPost != NULL) {
    print '<div class="newer_post">Newer:'. $nextPost .'</div>';
  };
  if ($prevPost != NULL) {
    print '<div class="older_post">Older:'. $prevPost .'</div>';
  };
?>
```

I've created a display suite "custom field" and have input the above using the "Display Suite Code" input formatter.

I've added a "colorbox" view mode display for "people" and it's working as it should, namely, my changes to that view mode reflect in the colorbox output. The prev/next module is working on all 9 people are indexed as reported by drush cron after configuring the module to index the people content type. I've run drush cc all to clear caches.

However, I am not seeing the rendered links as per the above custom code. Nothing prints in the region where I have set the custom field to output.